# How to install package to use module Location?

Tags: ocaml, opam

I find a program use module Location,I use ocamlc to compile it,but got error:

Unbound module Location

I try this:opam install Location

got:No package named Location found

so how to use module Location ?

I found it's very hard and boring,the document is not good too,the doc

https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Location.html

do not tell me the package name that I need to use opam to install

so how to use module Location?thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile it with `-package compiler-libs.common`.

For example to compile `Main.ml` with the following content:

```
let () =
  print_string !Location.input_name
```

use this command:

```
ocamlbuild -package compiler-libs.common Main.native
```

Also check [this](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/parsing.html).

Comment: Thanks!It works fine.I use vscode+merlin to write ocaml code.If I use ocamlc to build the ocaml program,vscode+merlin can read the package and class info well,but if use ocamlbuild ,vscode+merlin can't read it well,give me errors.Is there some method to resolve it?